# Windows 10 Windows Key + Number

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to use the WindowsKey + Number shortcut on Windows 10, however it doesn't seem to work right for duplicate windows.

[image]

In the above, when I press Win+1, it gives me the first Visual Studio Code window, and when I press Win+2, it displays the Chrome window (which is technically the third window).

On Ubuntu for example, Super+2 would display the second VSC window. Is there a tweak for Windows to do that? Thanks in advance :)

I also noticed I can press Win+1 repeatedly to switch between the VSC editors, but this is 2 key presses instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Windows groups windows that are generated by the same program.

So in your case you have two such groups : Visual Studio Code and Chrome.

Win+1 will give you the windows of the Visual Studio Code group,
among which you may further choose one.
Win+2 will give the second group, which is Chrome.

Comment: FYI: To switch between the two Visual Studio Code windows, you would simply, press Win+1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Win + T will show the groups contents too, then you navigate with arrows. But if you want to reduce the amount of stokes, using win + # then repeat tap number while holding Win is the shortest method I could find.